# TypeError: list indices must be integers - Dealing with money

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I'm trying to "execute" a (fake) buy order on a stock.  I hit an error at the `cash = cashcheck["cash"]` line.  It's saying that the indices must be integers, but we're talking about money, so it can't be an int because there's decimals involved... or so I think.

Help is greatly appreciated!

Code:

```
@app.route("/buy", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def buy():
    """Buy shares of stock"""

    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("/buy.html")
    else:

        # collect user input - symbol
        symbol = request.form.get("symbol").upper()

        # if input is blank or symbol doesn't exist, return apology
        if not symbol:
            return apology("You must enter a stock symbol.", 300)

        # collect user input - # of shares
        shares = int(request.form.get("shares"))

        # if blank or not a positive integer, return apology
        if not shares:
            return apology("Enter a valid number of shares.", 300)

        # pull current price info from API
        quote = lookup(symbol)
        shareprice = quote["price"]
        totalprice = shareprice * shares

        # check users table to see how much cash user has
        cashcheck = db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = :userid", userid = session["user_id"])

        cash = cashcheck["cash"]

        if cash >= totalprice:
            # in transactions table, insert userID, symbol, shares, shareprice, and totalprice
            # transID should be autogenerated and autoincremented.  date is also autofilled by SQLite.
            db.execute("INSERT INTO transactions (userID, symbol, shares, shareprice, totalprice) VALUES (:userid, :symbol, :shares, :shareprice, :totalprice)",
            userid=session["user_id"], symbol=symbol, shares=shares, shareprice=shareprice, totalprice=totalprice)

            cash = cash - totalprice

            # update cash balance
            db.execute("UPDATE users SET cash = :cash WHERE id = :userid", userid = session["user_id"])

            #return index
            return ("/")
        else:
            # else, return apology (not enough cash)
            return apology("Not enough cash balance to make execute this order.", 300)
```

Error:

```
ERROR:application:Exception on /buy [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/ubuntu/finance/helpers.py", line 34, in decorated_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/finance/application.py", line 86, in buy
    if cashcheck["cash"] >= totalprice:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: what is `cashback`? Add an example value of it

Comment: `cashcheck` is a list of rows that matched the query.  If you're only expecting one row to match, use `cashcheck[0]["cash"]`.

Comment: @AbhisekSingh that's not the issue at all. `cashcheck` is a list, which is only indexable with integers. `"cash"` is a string, thus the error.

Comment: @JohnGordon's answer solved that error!  Perhaps stupidly, it didn't occur to me that it was returning a list with just one result, in my head it was just returning the result.  Thanks!  Now onto solving the rest of the errors lol.  Feel free to write that out as an answer so I can mark it approved and give you the credit for it 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cashcheck` is a list of rows that matched the query.

If you're only expecting one row to match, use `cashcheck[0]["cash"]`.